# Python PermissionError uploading to an Azure Datalake folder

Tags: python, azure, azure-data-lake

I am trying to upload a file to azure datalake using python script.

I am able to download a file from the datalake, but the uploading raise a permission error, whereas i checked all permissions at all levels (Read Write Execute and the option for the decendants).

```
## works fine
multithread.ADLDownloader(adls, lpath='C:\\Users\\User1\\file1.txt', rpath='/Test/', nthreads=64, overwrite=True,
                          buffersize=4194304,
                          blocksize=4194304)

## Raise error
multithread.ADLUploader(adls, rpath='/Test', lpath='C:\\Users\\User1\\HC',
                        nthreads=64 , chunksize=268435456, buffersize=4194304, blocksize=4194304, client=None, run=True,
                        overwrite=False, verbose=True)
```

the error:

```
File "C:\Users\Python37-32\test_azure.py", line 64, in <module>
    overwrite=False, verbose=True)
  File "C:\Users\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\azure\datalake\store\multithread.py", line 442, in __init__
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\azure\datalake\store\multithread.py", line 548, in run
    self.client.run(nthreads, monitor)
  File "C:\Users\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\azure\datalake\store\transfer.py", line 525, in run
    raise DatalakeIncompleteTransferException('One more more exceptions occured during transfer, resulting in an incomplete transfer. \n\n List of exceptions and errors:\n {}'.format('\n'.join(error_list)))
azure.datalake.store.exceptions.DatalakeIncompleteTransferException: One more more exceptions occured during transfer, resulting in an incomplete transfer. 

 List of exceptions and errors:

C:\Users\User1\HC\AC.TXT -> \Test\AC.TXT, chunk \Test\AC.TXT 0: errored, "PermissionError('/Test/AC.TXT')"
```

Does somebody have an idea of the problem ?

Comment: Azure datalake store can be funny about owners of folders. Did you use the same tenant, uid, and password to create `/Test/` as you are using trying to write to `AC.TXT`?

Answer (score 0):

The azure account I am using has got all the privileges on the Datalake, but the Azure Application didn't.